# Complexity (beginner question)

Tags: language-agnostic, computer-science, complexity-theory

What is the complexity of these statements?

```
for(int k = 1; k < n; k++)
    for(int i = 0; i < n-k; i++){
        //O(1) operation here
    }
```

Explanation appreciated.

Comment: What do _you_ think it is? How did you arrive at that conclusion? We like to see _some_ work done by askers.

Comment: O(n log(n)). This is what I think, but I have great doubts, so I ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First go in the outer loop, you do the operation `n-1` times.
Second go you do it `n-2` times, ... Add those all up and you'll end up with `(n)*(n-1)/2` operations.

To see that sum, write it from 1 to (n-1), then from (n-1) to 1 and add each term one by one.

```
  1   2   3 ... n-3 n-2 n-1
n-1 n-2 n-3 ...   3   2   1
---------------------------
  n   n   n       n   n   n
```

So `2 * sum = (n-1) * n`.

So that's about `n²` in terms of complexity.

Comment: The OP may be interested to know that this is called a [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). There's a story about Gauss when he was a child.. his teacher told the class to sum all of the numbers from 1 to 100 to keep them busy. Gauss noticed this pattern and was able to calculate the answer rapidly, to the surprise of his teacher. **Edit:** I just realized this question is 5 months old.. no idea how I got here.